# Opening an image in Python on app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-imaging-library, nonetype

So I have a piece of code that works perfectly fine when I run it in my console, however it does not when I try to run it on app engine.

```
from lib.PIL import Image
import urllib, cStringIO
@endpoints.method(ImageCreateRequest, DummyResponse, http_method='POST', name='image_create')
def image_create(self, request):
    file = cStringIO.StringIO(urllib.urlopen(URL).read())
    img = Image.open(file)
    img.load()
    return DummyResponse(
        response=str(img.size)
    )
```

I get the following error

in _new

```
new.mode = im.mode

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mode'
```

**Edit: exact traceback**

```
Encountered unexpected error from ProtoRPC method implementation: AttributeError ('NoneType' object has no attribute 'mode')

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/wsgi/service.py", line 181, in protorpc_service_app
response = method(instance, request)
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/endpoints-1.0/endpoints/api_config.py", line 1331, in invoke_remote
return remote_method(service_instance, request)
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/remote.py", line 414, in invoke_remote_method
response = method(service_instance, request)
File "/base/data/home/apps/myproj/1.392969200987483659/post_api.py", line 100, in image_create
img = Image.open(file)
File "/base/data/home/apps/myproj/1.392969200987483659/lib/PIL/Image.py", line 1969, in open
if init():
File "/base/data/home/apps/myproj/1.392969200987483659/lib/PIL/Image.py", line 355, in init
__import__(f, globals(), locals(), [])
File "/base/data/home/apps/myproj/1.392969200987483659/lib/PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py", line 92, in <module>
Palm8BitColormapImage = build_prototype_image()
File "/base/data/home/apps/myproj/1.392969200987483659/lib/PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py", line 82, in build_prototype_image
image = Image.new("L", (1,len(_Palm8BitColormapValues),))
File "/base/data/home/apps/myproj/1.392969200987483659/lib/PIL/Image.py", line 1763, in new
return Image()._new(core.fill(mode, size, color))
File "/base/data/home/apps/myproj/1.392969200987483659/lib/PIL/Image.py", line 463, in _new
new.mode = im.mode
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mode'

I am not too sure why something so simple would be working in the console but not on app engine. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: If it works locally but not in production, it might be that you are using a library that the production environment doesn't support.

Comment: you should add the exact traceback - the code you show doesn't match the error/statement you show.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I now added the full traceback, hope it helps.

Comment: did you pip install PIL into the lib directory or use the app engine module ?

Comment: I have PIL in my lib directory and use this import : from lib.PIL import Image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a production issue you should try this - 
remove the PIL module from the lib folder that you installed on your own.

go to app.yaml and paste this under the libraries section (if there isn't one paste this whole) -

`libraries:
  - name: PIL
    version: latest`

call the appengine based module by -

```
from PIL import Image
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked, even though I am not too sure why. I am fairly new to app engine and don't understand yet the difference between a lib import and the app engine based module import.

Comment: @AlWld there are a few libraries that have a few changes from the independent builds inorder to efficiently work via app-engine. you should do the pip install in the lib folder for all other libraries except for the one mentioned in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27

Comment: @AlWld - haha no problem. an upvote is much appreciated :P